# classic asp multiple button click

Tags: asp-classic

I have 2 asp pages.

- Feedback_Administration_Update.asp
- Feedback_Administration.asp

My HTML form:

```
<form ACTION="Feedback_Administration_Update.asp" METHOD=POST NAME="form">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:Checkit();" name="btnSubmit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="javascript:document.location=location">
  <input type="button" value="Send Response to Requester" name="btnSubmit" onclick="javascript:Checkit();"/>
</form>
```

Code in Feedback_Administration_Update.asp file:

```vbs
dim buttonPressed
buttonPressed=Request.Form("btnSubmit")
select case buttonPressed
    case "Submit"
        'update database code 
        Response.Redirect "feedback_administration.asp?ID=" & regEx.Replace((request.form("ID")), "''") & "&lstPages=" & Trim(Request("lstPages")) & "&view=" & Request("view")& "&strSuccess1=" &"Success"
    case "Send Response to Requester"
        'mail  task code 
End Select
```

I am not sure why they are not working on clicking any button.

When I click on submit the page, it should update the code, when I click on submit *Send Response to Requester*, it should send email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of button inputs is not sent to the server. You need to use ordinary submit buttons, and to have validation code you can cancel their onclick event:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return Checkit();" name="btnSubmit" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Response to Requester" name="btnSubmit" onclick="return Checkit();" />
```

To make it work, change your JavaScript function in two ways. First, don't make it submit the form and second have it return `true` upon successful validation and `false` otherwise, e.g.:

```
function Checkit() {
    //validate your stuff..
    if ([all is good]) {
        //don't submit the form here, the submit button will do that.
        return true;
    }

    //indicate that something was wrong, cancel form submission:
    return false;
}
```

Having this in place will cause `Request.Form("btnSubmit")` to hold the desired value.

Comment: Thank you ,yes I had to change the button type as "submit" instead of button type.